# WCF- console hosting

Tags: c#, wcf, console, localhost, hosting

I am just wondering.. I've created working WCF Service, where serwer is a console application. This works only when I launch the host within the Visual Studio, is this right? I mean when I try to launch in from *.exe, it seems to work, but then my `localhost` page shows blank page and client crashes.

I know I can use IIS, but is that correct behaviour (as I think it is)?

**Host**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using GettingStartedLib;

namespace GettingStartedHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/");

            ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), uri);

            try
            {
            selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new WSHttpBinding(), "CalculatorService");

                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;              
                selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                selfHost.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Serwer jest gotowy!");
                Console.WriteLine("Naciśnij <ENTER>, by go zamknąć.");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();

                selfHost.Close();

            }
            catch (CommunicationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wystąpił wyjątek: {0}",e.Message);
                selfHost.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICalculator" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/CalculatorService"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICalculator"
                contract="ServiceReference1.ICalculator" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICalculator" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: show code of your host

Comment: I've just posted it.

Comment: I don't have configurated App.config for the host. Why should I have it?

Answer (score 2):

> This works only when I launch the host within the Visual Studio, is
>   this right?

Absolutely NO!

> I mean when I try to launch in from *.exe, it seems to work, but then
>   my localhost page shows blank page and client crashes.

Their is nothing wrong with your code and I tried it multiple times "*it works*". The only thing I saw missing are mex endpoint and policy version but it seems not important to cause your localhost into blank page and make your client crashes.

How did you call your service in the browser?

If you call it this way think every thing is fine.

> `http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/` -> Result is okay

[image]

But if you call it like this:

> `http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/CalculatorService` -> Result is
>   blank page

[image]

This is my Console App.config setting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

This is my Service App.config. I remove all not unnecessary since we doing it programmatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>    
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This is my auto generated client config upon Adding Service Reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator" />
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/CalculatorService"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator"
                contract="ServiceReference1.ICalculator" name="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator">
                <!-- This is new to me and I don't know why it is here??? hmmm... I don't have any idea with this -->
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="myDomainName@Domain.com" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Note :** At first when I ran my *.exe host directly without administrator privilege I doesn't allow me to bind in port. And I tested my client to call the service and it is also working. I added service reference in my client here.

Comment: I call the service correctly with "/" at the end and I run it with administrator privelege and still I get blank page and the client crashes. Could I miss something that is important when I call it from *.exe not from within VS?

Comment: I replicated your scenario exactly the same with yours. I think you need to add some info here.

Comment: Well then I don't get it. Everything is just fine from within VS. When I run it from *.exe. There is that blank page..

1) You run the host from Debug version?
2) Did you change anything in app.config for the Host (I have it empty, cause I assume I run the serwer from the code)
3) When I launch it from *.exe I don't get the WCF Server message saying that serewer has started- is thath OK?
4) Is that possible that the Host can't access app.config from the library after it's not within the VS?

I just don't know what's going on.

Comment: My Console's app.config is a little different, but it was created automatically when I added ServiceRefference (I updated it) but it doesn't seem to work when I changed it to Your app.config, so that's not the point.

Can You answer my last question 3) and 4)? 
Or maybe some Windows setting doesn't allow me to run it from *.exe?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your *.exe as Administrator.